# Truncate & Simple Format String in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to take a string and render it with simple_format while at the same time truncating it. It works when I just use one or the other, but not when I do both. Why is this not doing simple_format and truncating simultaneously.

**Controller**

```
myString = "Apple&#8217;s New Laptop"
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_format truncate( myString, :length => 20 ) %>
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  What is the output in your view?

Comment: I still get "Apple&#8217;s New Laptop"

Comment: Is it actually ending up as `Apple&amp;#8217;s New Laptop` on the page?

Comment: Yup. Not changing at all, except the truncating is working.

Comment: What do you wish to et for the example?

Comment: This ended up working: <%= simple_format myString[0...20] %>

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to `truncate` **after** you have used `simple_format` on the string. Since truncate escapes the string by default, you have to use the `escape: false` option.

```
> myString = "Apple&#8217;s New Laptop"

> truncate(simple_format(myString), escape: false) 
> => "<p>Apple&#8217;s New Laptop..."

> truncate(simple_format(myString), escape: false, length: 19)
> => "<p>Apple&#8217;s..."
```

This has the potential to create unbalanced HTML tags by cutting the `</p>` for example, so use carefully.

Comment: Warning: this solution can create unbalanced `<p></p>` tags by truncating the trailing `</p>`'s

Answer (score 1):

There was something changed in the truncate-helper in Rails 4.
The documentation does tells us:

> The result is marked as HTML-safe, but it is escaped by default, unless :escape is false.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate

Rails normally escapes all strings. If you just want to put some unicode chars in strings in your code, you can do it by using the \u notation  with the hexadecimal code. Then truncate will also count the char as exactly one char.

```
myString = "Apple\u2019s New Laptop"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but useful to someone else. This worked for me.

```
 <%= truncate(myString, escape: false, length: 20 ) %>
```